# What is the currency of the field "value" in ERC20 transfers?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20

I'm trying to understand every fields in an erc20 transfers. But I don't find any informations about the currency of the `value` field :

https://etherscan.io/tokentxns

Can someone explain me ?

Comment: It represents the amount of tokens transferred.

Answer (score 2):

If T is the name of the ERC-20 token you are looking at, then to find the number of T tokens involved in the transaction, take `value` and divide by 10^`decimals`. `decimals` is a value set by the programmer in the contract itself.

Why not have `value` directly represent the number of T tokens? Because the EVM doesn’t handle floating-point values, programmers instead use fixed-point numbers. For example, if `decimals` is 2, then `value` is divided by 10^2=100. So if `value` is 1234, this represents 12.34 T tokens. Thus, `decimals` determines how divisible a token is into fractions of that token.

Comment: `value is the number of T tokens, divided by 10^decimals` Shouldn't this be multiplied?

Comment: @RaghavSood you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The value is the units of a token transferred in that transaction.

Note that the units are similar to ethereum, in the sense that the base unit is what we would normally look for after the decimal.

For example, for the [ZRX](https://etherscan.io/token/0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498) token, the base unit is the same as for ether, 1 wei.

Therefore, a transfer of 1 ZRX will have an event log value of 1*10^18, or `1000000000000000000`.